# how to insert list of string in mysql using php

Tags: php

i need to insert list of string into mysql, so how do i do it?

```
<?php
require "connection.php";

$res_rname= "Baler";
$res_per_name= "ken";
$res_id= "102";

$datess="2018-08-16, 2018-08-17, 2018-08-17";
$mydate=explode(',',$datess);
$dates = $mydate;


$sql_query = "Insert into res_event_table ( res_id, res_check_in_out, 
res_room_name, res_name) values ( '$res_id','$val', '$res_rname', 
'$res_per_name')";
if($dates>0)
{
    foreach($dates as $val){
        $result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql_query);
            if (!$result){
            echo "failed" .mysqli_connect_error;
            }else{
            echo "Reservation Success";
       }
    }
 }

?>
```

this is how far i get, it insert the other value but the list of date string leaves empty space in my database 
[i read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826599/inserting-a-simple-list-into-mysql-table-php)
but it doesnt work for me i dont know why.

Comment: `echo "failed" .mysqli_connect_error;` that isn't the correct error checking method. That's for connection, not for querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a lots of simple mistakes, correct code is as below,

```
<?php
require "connection.php";

$res_rname= "Baler";
$res_per_name= "ken";
$res_id= "102";

$datess="2018-08-16, 2018-08-17, 2018-08-17";
$mydate=explode(',',$datess);
$dates = $mydate;  // No need to create a separate variable but ok for now 


if(count($dates)>0)
{
    foreach($dates as $val){
        $sql_query = "Insert into res_event_table ( res_id, res_check_in_out, 
res_room_name, res_name) values ( '$res_id','$val', '$res_rname', 
'$res_per_name')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql_query);
            if (!$result){
            echo "failed" .mysqli_connect_error;
            }else{
            echo "Reservation Success";
       }
    }
 }

?>
```

Comment: Your answer is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know but knowing ken's knowledge it's ok for him.

Comment: @ken you can upvote answer clicking on the ^ button left of the answer.

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to upvote but i appreciate your help and i will upvote it if have enough rep. thanks for your help @bhagwanparge

Comment: you should escape strings in case of input is coming from outside of this code